# How to generate automatically the sum price of a dynamic table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a web-based POS. I have two table, one is for displaying the search products using jquery and when I clicked the product it will transfer to the second table. So my second table is dynamically dependent of what the user clicked. This is my table look like with css.

[image]

I want to get the total price of Sub.Total column automatically and display to the bottom specially in the Total p tag.

This is my html table code.

```
<table id="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Barcode</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Sub.Total</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableData">
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="table1">
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Barcode</td>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Unit</td>
            <td>Stocks</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="products">   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my query from search box.

```
$show   = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '$name%' ";
    $query  = mysqli_query($db,$show);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class='js-add' data-barcode=".$row['id']." data-product=".$row['product_name']." data-price=".$row['sell_price']." data-unt=".$row['unit']."><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['product_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>₱".$row['sell_price']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['unit']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['quantity']."</td>";
        }
    }
```

This is for displaying the cliked rows from searched products.

```
    $('body').on('click','.js-add',function(){
        var target = $(this);
        var product = target.attr('data-product');
        var price = target.attr('data-price');
        var barcode = target.attr('data-barcode');
        var unit = target.attr('data-unt');     
        swal("Enter number of item to buy:", {
            content: "input",
        })
        .then((value) => {
            if (value == "") {
                swal("Error","Entered none!","error");
            }else{
                var qtynum = parseInt(value);
                if (isNaN(qtynum)){
                    swal("Error","Please input a valid number!","error");
                }else{
                    var total = value * price;
                    $('#tableData').append("<tr><td>"+barcode+"</td
                    <td>"+product+"</td>
                   <td>"+accounting.formatMoney(price,{symbol:"₱",format: "%s %v"})+"</td><td>"+unit+"</td>
                   <td>"+value+"</td>
                   <td class='totalPrice'>"+accounting.formatMoney(total,{symbol:"₱",format: "%s %v"})+"</td>
                   <td><button class='btn btn-danger' type='button' id='delete-row'>&times</button><tr>");          
               }
            }
        });
    });
```

I'd tried this code but it return NaN.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var TotalValue = 0;
    $("#tableData tr").each(function(){
          TotalValue += parseFloat($(this).find('.totalPrice').text().replace(/,/g, "₱"));
    });
    alert(TotalValue);
});
```

I'd tried modifying the code but I cant get the job done. Hope someone will help about this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Updated answer.

Based off what you tried here would be a working solution using your logic.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var TotalValue = 0;
    var TotalPriceArr = $('.totalPrice').get()
    $(TotalPriceArr).each(function(){
          TotalValue +=parseInt($(this).text().replace('₱', ''))
    });
    alert(TotalValue);
});
```

Comment: This else condition is fetching only once. What if there are 3 products?

Comment: From the looks of it the else would run for each product you try and add right? If not I'm failing to see how you would add multiple products.

Comment: Yes, it only add once. When I click another product it adds again by one so it get the value of the last product.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code by this one `var TotalValue = 0;
    var TotalPriceArr = $('#tableData tr .totalPrice').get()
    $(TotalPriceArr).each(function(){
          TotalValue +=parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g, "").replace("₱",""))
    });
    alert(TotalValue);` and it works.

Comment: Do you know how to print the TotalValue on html file? on a <p> tag?

Comment: give the p an ID like <p id="totalValue"> </p> then do $("#totalValue").text(TotalValue)
. It'd be awesome if you could mark my answer correct :D

Comment: Sure why not. Thanks.